# HTML Formatting in json data that comes out raw

Tags: javascript, html, json

I imported json data from this website that provides open data for garbage retrieval. On my website I have a search bar that searches through that to provide the relevant data from the garbage data. Each piece of data has a title and has details about that piece of garbage.

The problem I have is that when I try to output the details part of it, it comes embedded with html formatting stuff it is all properly escaped for display in html. When I try to output it from js by changing a text element on my page using innerhtml, it comes out with all the escape formatting still there. I have copy pasted it and displayed it separately and it displays properly so I know there isn't a problem with the json text.

```
var garbageInfo = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
...
for (j = 0;j<garbageInfo.length;j++){
        var dataTitle = garbageInfo[j].title.toUpperCase()
        if((dataTitle.indexOf(input)!=-1)){
            body = garbageInfo[j].body;
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = body
        }
    };
```

For example the output will come out as `<ul> <li>Place item in the <strong>Garbage Bin.</strong></li> </ul>`
Where it should be the same but with the proper formatting.

Sorry I am quite new to this so I imagine I am doing something wrong I am sorry if this is some repetitive question but I searched around and I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

Thank you

Comment: What is `ourRequest.responseText`. It sounds like what you're saying is `json` isn't actually `json`. It's `html` with escape characters in it. I you paste the value of `ourRequest.responseText` or a simplified version of it, it would help determine what the issue is.

Comment: Your code looks fine. It sounds like the response has everything double-encoded.

Comment: @mwilson If it weren't JSON he would get an error from `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Outstanding point.